# Парсинг json javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Пытаюсь спарсить значение,полученное от vk api

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember?group_id=habr&user_id=1&extended=1&v=5.44

function gotData( data){
    var i, post, html="";
   /* if( !data  ||  !data.response  ||  !data.response.items) {
        console.error( "VK returned some crap:", data);
        return;
    }*/


    $('#vk').html(data.response.member);
}


$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember",
    data: {
      group_id: "habr",
       user_id: "1",
       extended:"1"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",    
    success: gotData,
});
```

Без проверки ответ выводится,с проверкой нет.
Еще проблема,не хочет выводить несколько значений
http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/okrx4zzy/14/

Comment: Вы не смотрите, что вам возвращает ВК. А дело в том, что он не всегда возвращает `items`. Это зависит от метода. Поэтому у вас отрабатывает `!data.response.items`  и, как следствие,  `return` .... в `groups.isMember`  свойства `items`  нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не подскажите еще есть метод users.get, если ему в параметр вставить только access token он выведет uid,first_name,last_name. запрос нормально выводит,но опять же при обращении data.response.uid ничего не происходит,пробовал в том числе и так data.response[1] ,т к там массив

Comment: Если не указывать версию, то по умолчанию прилетает `uid`, в поздних версиях если указывать в параметре, например `&v=5.44` то прилетает уже `id`. Скорее всего вы указываете версию и прилетает именно `id`. Выводите то, что приходит от АПИ хотя бы в консоль `console.log(data)` и смотрите конкретно структуру ответа, чтобы не ошибиться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, частично получилось data.response[0].id,но уже data.response[1].first_name не выводит,хотя по формату он так возвращает https://vk.com/dev/users.get

Comment: Если запрашивается один юзер, то логично, что все лежит в [0] элементе. `data.response[0].id`, `data.response[0].first_name` и `data.response[0].last_name` соответственно...Один объект лежит в одной и только одной ячейке массива, а не разбросан по разным ячейкам.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,большое спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, стоит оформить комментарии в виде ответа :-D

Comment: @Grundy Вы не NicolasChabanovskyi =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский :-D я только учусь :-D :-D :-D